# Laravel multi-tenancy with subdomains: Undefined variable $errors and Session store not set on request on login and register page

Tags: laravel, authentication, multi-tenant

I am implementing a multi-tenant Laravel application using `archtechx/tenancy` package. I have set up separate databases for each tenant and have created a Tenant model to manage tenants. I am using the central database to store information about tenants and their assigned modules.

I am facing two errors on my login page:

- Undefined variable $errors
- Session store not set on request.

Here's what I have tried so far:

- I have set the `SESSION_DOMAIN` value in my .env file to
  `.localhost:8000`
- I have set the `SESSION_DRIVER` to the database in my
  config/session.php file.

One more thing I try, I remove all the errors variable from `register.balde` file and submit the form then I receive them in my central database but when I get `users` from `UserController` they are using the right tenant Database.

here is my `tenant.php`

```
Auth::routes();
Route::middleware([
    'web',
    'auth',
    InitializeTenancyByDomain::class,
    PreventAccessFromCentralDomains::class,
    CheckModuleMiddleware::class,
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        // dd(\App\Models\User::all());
        return 'This is your multi-tenant application. The id of the current tenant is ' . tenant('id');
    });

    Route::resource('users', App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class);
});
```

Despite these efforts, I am still facing the same errors. Can anyone suggest what could be causing these errors and how to fix them?

Comment: I have the exact same issue with a $errors variable which can not be found on the login page after moving to a tenant aware infrastructure with this package. Have you solved this in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make changes in you .env
Session_domain=`*.localhost`
session_driver=file
and if using sanctrum for authentication
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=`*.localhost`